# how to update pub version

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-pub

When I run the command >pub version the console shows Pub 1.9.0-dev.0.0

My DartEditor and SDK version is 1.9.0-dev.3.0

How can I update pub to have similar version.

Thanks

Comment: The pub version should be the same as the version of the SDK. Please check how your path is configured. What version does '> dart --version' report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Pub is bound to the SDK.

Comment: Maybe the Dart team only updated the Pub version when something changes and/or stable relrases.